# How to replace/reinstall packages from backports to normal repository

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg, backport

On 18.04 I have the backports enabled in /etc/apt/soures.list. My questions are:

1. How can I find out which packages are installed from backports? The tips from https://serverfault.com/questions/109442/how-can-i-list-all-installed-packages-from-lenny-backports for Debian Lenny do not work.
2. I want to go from backports to the normal repository. How can I do it without a lot of commands? By doing this I can compare the versions and decide if there would be configuration/downgrading issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part
should work with `apt-show-versions` Install it and run `apt-show-versions | grep bionic-backports`

The second part is the tricky one. I would remove backports and make it over apt pinning

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu

Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001


Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release  a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Refresh package cache `sudo apt update` then you can simulate first `apt --dry-run full-upgrade`